# C# does not actually copy the whole "big struct" on passing argument as seen from IL?

Tags: c#, compilation

I have heard often that with value type we have to be careful when passing them into a method, since the value will be copied. If the struct is big then it might be a problem.

However I took a look at IL of this code :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public struct Big
    {
        public int a, b, c, d;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Big big = new Big();
        UseBig(big);
        big.a += 7;
    }

    private static void UseBig(Big big)
    {
        big.a += 1;
        big.b += 1;
    }
}
```

IL :

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  3
    .locals init (valuetype Program/Big V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldloca.s   V_0
    IL_0003:  initobj    Program/Big
    IL_0009:  ldloc.0
    IL_000a:  call       void Program::UseBig(valuetype Program/Big)
    IL_000f:  nop
    IL_0010:  ldloca.s   V_0
    IL_0012:  dup
    IL_0013:  ldfld      int32 Program/Big::a
    IL_0018:  ldc.i4.7
    IL_0019:  add
    IL_001a:  stfld      int32 Program/Big::a
    IL_001f:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Main
.method private hidebysig static void  UseBig(valuetype Program/Big big) cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarga.s   big
    IL_0003:  dup
    IL_0004:  ldfld      int32 Program/Big::a
    IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_000a:  add
    IL_000b:  stfld      int32 Program/Big::a
    IL_0010:  ldarga.s   big
    IL_0012:  dup
    IL_0013:  ldfld      int32 Program/Big::b
    IL_0018:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0019:  add
    IL_001a:  stfld      int32 Program/Big::b
    IL_001f:  ret
  } // end of method Program::UseBig
```

The mechanism to call into a function is that it `load location of local variable #0` to the stack, then inside the function it uses `load address of argument`. Then we could `load field` and `store field` by using this address. `dup` because the `load` and `store` will consume the address at the top of stack.

An another run with `ref` :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public struct Big
    {
        public int a, b, c, d;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Big big = new Big();
        UseBig(ref big);
        big.a += 7;
    }

    private static void UseBig(ref Big big)
    {
        big.a += 1;
        big.b += 1;
    }
}
```

IL :

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  3
    .locals init (valuetype Program/Big V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldloca.s   V_0
    IL_0003:  initobj    Program/Big
    IL_0009:  ldloca.s   V_0
    IL_000b:  call       void Program::UseBig(valuetype Program/Big&)
    IL_0010:  nop
    IL_0011:  ldloca.s   V_0
    IL_0013:  dup
    IL_0014:  ldfld      int32 Program/Big::a
    IL_0019:  ldc.i4.7
    IL_001a:  add
    IL_001b:  stfld      int32 Program/Big::a
    IL_0020:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Main
.method private hidebysig static void  UseBig(valuetype Program/Big& big) cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.0
    IL_0002:  dup
    IL_0003:  ldfld      int32 Program/Big::a
    IL_0008:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0009:  add
    IL_000a:  stfld      int32 Program/Big::a
    IL_000f:  ldarg.0
    IL_0010:  dup
    IL_0011:  ldfld      int32 Program/Big::b
    IL_0016:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0017:  add
    IL_0018:  stfld      int32 Program/Big::b
    IL_001d:  ret
  } // end of method Program::UseBig
```

At entering function it instead use `load local variable address` so the address goes in instead of its value, inside the function instead of loading an address of it we `load argument` value directly because it is already an address. Everything we do here will then affect the value at caller because it is done to that caller's address, not to the argument variable space. Thus this is the behavior of `ref`.

The questions are :

1. So actually it does not depends on any other variables in my `struct` (`c` and `d`)? No matter how big it is the program actually pass the whole struct as a single address anyways. Then where is the big cost that people keeps talking about?
2. Under the hood `ref` actually does not save any "struct copy cost"?

These IL code was obtained from https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Perhaps it is dependant on actual structure size, your's isn't _that_ big. Generally in programming, the risk is exhausting the stack due to excessive pushing of items on the stack or recursion

Comment: The first one has "load local #0" not "load location (address) of local #0"

Comment: @MickyD So you are saying that if I have 1000 of `long` instead of just 4 `int` the IL will change even though I am using just the first 2 variables?

Comment: Ok I missed the copy myself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, the copy is made by

```
ldloc.0
```

There is no address passed to the function.

Anyway, you can't rely on IL inspection for this, try looking at the generated native code.  Even in the first case inlining might happen and optimize away that copy.